# How to prove $x^5 + y^7 +11$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I’m so wired attacking reducibility using the fact that I’m on a field and playing with orders of elements to show there is no linear or quadratic factors. But $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field and the multi variable part of it is confusing. Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: Do you know Eisenstein's criterion? Think of this as a polynomial in $\mathbb Z[y][x]$, or even $\mathbb Q[y][x]$.

Comment: Just got used to using Einsensteins criterion but when computing the gcd of the polynomial and its derivative si have a fraction so clearly I’m wrong

Comment: That I don't understand. No derivatives necessary.

Comment: This is what I have: consider identifications via natural isomorphisms \mathbb{Z} [x][y]. Wanting to show that y^7 +11 is divisible by some prime p in Z(y)[x] and not by p^2. So when I test for repeated factors computing the gcd of this polynomial and its derivative:

Comment: (y^7 + 11) - fraction, not sure of that step because we are in Z

Comment: But why do you care about repeated factors? (And I still don't find fractions...) Can you show that $y^7+11$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[y]$?

Comment: I was confused since I thought I had to show that y^7+11 is not a unit and has no repeated factors. My confusion arises because I have done this problems for fields. The idea of the repeated factors is to argue something like

Comment: That's not true. Eisenstein-type arguments don't involve questions of multiple roots. Look back in your text.

Comment: The term is a unit then can’t apply the criterion

Comment: $y^7 + 11$ is not a uniit in $\mathbb{Z}[y]$.  In fact, it is a prime.